# Bootstrap Carousel breaks html layout with XSLT on Sharepoint

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, xslt, bootstrap-carousel

I am facing this weird issue, please follow to the rest:

1- I have this static carousel html code: (which is working on browser)

```
<div class="Awareness-section no-padding col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div id="Awareness-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#Awareness-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active">1</li>
          <li data-target="#Awareness-carousel" data-slide-to="1">2</li>
          <li data-target="#Awareness-carousel" data-slide-to="2">3</li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active">
            <p class="Awareness-title">Awareness 1</p>
            <p class="Awareness-desc">Content 1</p>
        </div>

          <div class="item">
            <p class="Awareness-title">Awareness 2</p>
            <p class="Awareness-desc">Content 2</p>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <p class="Awareness-title">Awareness 3</p>
            <p class="Awareness-desc">Content 3</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    <p class="Awareness-view-all"><a href="">View All</a></p>
</div>
```

---

2- Then I made it dynamic with sharepoint's content query webpart (XSLT) like this:

```
  <xsl:variable name="BeginColumn" select="string('&lt;div id=&quot;Awareness-carousel&quot; class=&quot;carousel slide&quot;&gt;&lt;!-- Indicators --&gt;&lt;ol class=&quot;carousel-indicators&quot;&gt;&lt;li data-target=&quot;#Awareness-carousel&quot; data-slide-to=&quot;0&quot;&gt;1&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li data-target=&quot;#Awareness-carousel&quot; data-slide-to=&quot;1&quot;&gt;2&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li data-target=&quot;#Awareness-carousel&quot; data-slide-to=&quot;2&quot;&gt;3&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ol&gt;&lt;!-- Wrapper for slides --&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;carousel-inner&quot; role=&quot;listbox&quot;&gt;')" />
                          <xsl:variable name="EndColumn" select="string('&lt;!-- Left and right controls --&gt;&lt;a class=&quot;left carousel-control&quot; href=&quot;#Awareness-carousel&quot; role=&quot;button&quot; data-slide=&quot;prev&quot;&gt;&lt;span&gt;&lt;i class=&quot;fa fa-angle-left&quot;&gt;&lt;/i&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;sr-only&quot;&gt;Previous&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;a class=&quot;right carousel-control&quot; href=&quot;#Awareness-carousel&quot; role=&quot;button&quot; data-slide=&quot;next&quot;&gt;&lt;span&gt;&lt;i class=&quot;fa fa-angle-right&quot;&gt;&lt;/i&gt;&lt;/span&gt; &lt;span class=&quot;sr-only&quot;&gt;Next&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;aw-vall&quot;&gt;&lt;p class=&quot;Awareness-view-all&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;/Arabic/Pages/allawareness.aspx&quot;&gt;&#x639;&#x631;&#x636; &#x627;&#x644;&#x643;&#x644;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/div&gt;')" />
```

---

then
I added it in a webpart zone in the page layout:

```
<div class="Awareness-section no-padding col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <WebPartPages:WebPartZone id="AwarenessSection" runat="server" title="Awareness Webpart"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
</div>
```

---

3- I am adding 'active' class to first indicator and item, and initializing the carousel manually in the js:

```
$('.carousel-indicators li:first').addClass("active");
$('.carousel-inner .item:first').addClass("active");
$('#Awareness-carousel').carousel();
```

---

4- After all, the carousel worked fine, but the html layout of the page is breaking, the footer is going under the container:

---

**Before adding the carousel:**
[image]

---

**After adding the carousel:**
[image]

---

**Please help if anyone has a clue why this happening and what is the solutions to try ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see in the XSLT part there is a div in the `BeginColumn` that is not closed in the `EndColumn`.
Adding a `&lt;/div&gt;` in the beginning `EndColumn` of should fix your problem.

Comment: The problem is solved, everything is working fine now Thank you.